# animate scroll top in modal doesn't go from middle to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w7jydexf/) you can press button to scroll to element 13 in modal, and it works fine, until your scroll on top(scrolltop = 0), but if you scroll little bit down manual before clicking button and click button it doesn't scroll you to target or if click twice the second click scrolls to top when it must standing
on one place. How to fix it?
Browser: Firefox 62.0b6 (Quantum)

```
 $('button').on('click',function(){
      $('#modal').animate(
        { scrollTop: $('#item13').offset().top -80 }, 
        500);  
    });
```

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to stack overflow. Although I'm sure this is a frustrating bug, this is not the part of the site to ask people to debug your code or review it. You can ask this question on the Code Review section of the site perhaps, or if you have a specific question about animation with jQuery, that would be more appropriate https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Have a nice day!

Comment: debug or review of 5 lines of code?

Comment: Checkout this guide for how to ask a good on topic question https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Users are tasked with reviewing content of new users on this site to help them have a good time on stack overflow and learn to get the most out of what is a powerful and helpful tool. Plus we're here to try and help you avoid getting downvoted, which is never fun 

Comment: @JonChurch Hi Jon, this question would be most unwelcome on Code Review. Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/52915) and the [Code Review help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Code stripped from all context is one of the things we don't deal in.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it just adding current scroll to offset, just waste about 5 hours for it -_-

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
var currScroll = $('#modal').scrollTop();
console.log(t);
  $('#modal').animate(
    { scrollTop: $('#item13').offset().top -80 + currScroll }, 
    500);  
});
```